# Getting function instead of link

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So i have made a command for my friends' servers so we can have list of invites to our servers. When i run the bot and type ".servers" i'm getting <function owner.servers..serversInvite at 0x0000022903A75B40> instead of invite link.

````py
    @commands. command()
    async def servers(self, ctx):
        async def serversInvite(guild = discord.Guild):
            for guild in self.bot.guilds:
                channel = guild.text_channels[0]
                link = await channel.create_invite(max_age=0)
                invitelink = str(link)
            if link:
                msg = '```js\n'
                for guild in self.bot.guilds:
                    msg += f'ID: {guild.id} | Members: {guild.member_count} | Guild Name: {guild.name} | Owner: {guild.owner} | Server Invite: {serversInvite}\n'
                msg += '```'
                await ctx.send(msg)
            else:
                msg = '```js\n'
                for guild in self.bot.guilds:
                    msg += f'ID: int({guild.id}) | Members: {guild.member_count} | Guild Name: {guild.name} | Owner: {guild.owner} | \n'
                msg += '```'
                await ctx.send(msg)
````

Comment: You're sending `str({serversInvite}`. `serversInvite` is a function, so when you convert that to a string, you get that `<function ...>` text. You're not calling the function. When you don't put the parentheses at the end you're just referring to the function itself. I'd say that you need to call the function and get its value, but it appears that you're doing that within the `serversInvite` function itself, so that would be an infinite loop. I know nothing about Discord.py so I can't understand what you're trying to do there, or what you need to put there instead.

Comment: Yeah about str() i was testing different methods cuz i have no idea how i need to call that function. By default it was without the string and i have edited the code :)

Comment: Do you mean to say invitelink not SeverInvite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `invitelink` defined as:

`invitelink = str(link)`

is not used in your code.

Didn't you mean in the following line to use the `invitelink` in place of the `serversInvite`?

Before

```
msg += f'ID: {guild.id} ... | Server Invite: {serversInvite}\n'
```

After

```
msg += f'ID: {guild.id} ... | Server Invite: {invitelink}\n'
```

By the way, the serversInvite function parameter guild is not used, as the guild used later in the function is an item of self.bot.guilds.

EDIT 1: what about the following changes ?

````
@commands. command()
async def servers(self, ctx):
    async def serversInvite(guild = discord.Guild):
        for index, guild in enumerate(self.bot.guilds):
            channel = guild.text_channels[0]
            link = await channel.create_invite(max_age=0)
            invitelink = str(link)
            if link:
                msg = '```js\n'
                msg += f'ID: {guild.id} | Members: {guild.member_count} | Guild Name: {guild.name} | Owner: {guild.owner} | Server Invite: {invitelink}\n'
                msg += '```'
                await ctx.send(msg)
            else:
                msg = '```js\n'
                msg += f'ID: int({guild.id}) | Members: {guild.member_count} | Guild Name: {guild.name} | Owner: {guild.owner} | \n'
                msg += '```'
                await ctx.send(msg)
````

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply but when i use invitelink istead of serversInvite im getting the same invite for 2 different servers. Thats the whole problem and thats why i have changed it with serversinvite

Comment: You are using members of guild which is in turn an item of the self.bot.guilds, and it makes sens that you go through all of elements. But the inviteLink is the only one that is common to all the items, which would explain that you get the same invite.

Comment: Maybe you should move the if/else in the first for loop, so that they get the value of `inviteLink`. Now, you just get the last version of the `str(link)` value. Or you could try to do `guild.invitelink = str(link)` and then access the element with `guild.invitelink`

Comment: So with guild.invitelink is not working because im getting "AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'invitelink'"

Comment: Can you tell me why you have 2 for loops (nested) looping trough the same self.bot.guilds ?

Comment: Actually i was doing this for texting and my head is messed up with this code and dont know what i was doing..

Comment: check the revised version in the answer above, does it work?